# How to access a textbox text from gridview to a button Onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I am having textboxes and buttons in gridview. What I want is that when I click on those buttons the corresponding value in textbox is updated to database, so I need to access the textbox text in OnClick event. How can I do this?

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" 
            ForeColor="Black" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Save 1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave1" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave1_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Save 2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" Width="30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave2" runat="server" Text="Save"  OnClick="btnSave2_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Button Onclick Event:

```
protected void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //I want to access TextBox1 here.
    }
```

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Please have a look at this website they have a sample very similar to what you try to achieve. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
protected void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
     TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox; 

      //Access TextBox1 here.
      string myString = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: Although it is working but the textbox value is coming null. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly this is an example of how to get the TextBox value:

```
string CustomerID = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCustomerID")).Text;
```

Comment: But since my button click event is outside gridview, `e.RowIndex` will not work.

Comment: on click event trigger Update Command. The website i provided you will give you the details. it's very close to what you want

Comment: In the site example, they are using `FooterTemplate`, can you tell me where I should use it?

Comment: Although it is working but I have to create footer for this which I dont want. Do you have any other method?

Comment: Check the DeleteCustomer Function and also the Gridview Template. He passes a Command Argument with the value he wants to delete? From your example i don't see any datasource. If you don't have need to present data from database but only save new records you can use simple HTML5 table

Comment: Either Footer Template or Item Template the code is same there is no difference